# Bipolar Voltage to Current Converter

Tags: current, analog, current-source, converter

I need a circuit or component which converts bipolar voltage to bipolar current. I have found the [XTR111](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/sbos375c/sbos375c.pdf) from Texas Instruments and the [1B22](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1B22.pdf) from Analog Devices. However, they only convert 0-10 V to 0-20 mA current.

I to need convert -10V-0V to -10mA-0mA too (the opposite polarity range). How can I do that? Or can I add a circuit to work with 1B22 or XTR111?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Howland current pump: -

[image]

[**Here's**](http://michaelgellis.tripod.com/howland.html) an article that gives a lot of mathematical insight into it but is not inaccessible to the equation-hater.

[**AN-1515A**](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwioltSz3djKAhXEZw8KHQPGD0MQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fan%2Fsnoa474a%2Fsnoa474a.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGs8FDKBlOrerXORx_B1B3PvDdsoQ&sig2=RpGOWovxSrg159wgkNXnkA) is an article by TI on the subject.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have found a component that is XTR300 from texas instruments. This is the link: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr300.pdf.

Comment: It looks interesting but I can't say whether it will work for you. Watch out for the maximum capacitance (1uF) you can apply to the output.